# Javascript Navigation Output (Minified)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page where I output the following

This is the html in my template

```
<ul id="process"><span>Process: </span>
```

This is my minified Javascript (functions.js)

```
$(window).load(function () {
    var a = $("#slider").children("img");
    currentIndex = 0;
    slideCount = a.length;
    fadeDuration = 1E3;
    navigation = $("#process");
    navCnt = 0;
    navNumFix = 1;
    for (i = 0; i < slideCount; i++) navigation.append('<li><a href="#" class="navItem" data="' + navCnt+++'">' + navNumFix+++"</a></li>&#32;");
    $(".navItem").click(function () {
        var b = $(this).attr("data"),
            c = currentIndex;
        currentIndex = b;
        c != currentIndex && ($(a[c]).fadeOut(fadeDuration), $(a[currentIndex]).fadeIn(fadeDuration))
    })
});
```

For my slider this all outputs the ul tag and attaches the list item via Javascript as follows:

```
<ul id="process"><span>Process: </span>
<li><a href="#" class="navItem" data="0">1</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="navItem" data="1">2</a></li> 
</ul>
```

Instead of outputting the ul tag in my template, how can I output the ul tag only when the script calls for it? Kind of like the list item above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do... putting your template in display none at first, then showing it after adding your list elements :

```
<ul style="display:none" id="process"><span>Process: </span></ul>
```

Javascript :

```
$(window).load(function () {
    var a = $("#slider").children("img");
    currentIndex = 0;
    slideCount = a.length;
    fadeDuration = 1E3;
    navigation = $("#process");
    navCnt = 0;
    navNumFix = 1;
    for (i = 0; i < slideCount; i++) navigation.append('<li><a href="#" class="navItem" data="' + navCnt+++'">' + navNumFix+++"</a></li>&#32;");
    $(".navItem").click(function () {
        var b = $(this).attr("data"),
            c = currentIndex;
        currentIndex = b;
        c != currentIndex && ($(a[c]).fadeOut(fadeDuration), $(a[currentIndex]).fadeIn(fadeDuration))
    })

    // Display the ul if there are slides
    if(slideCount > 0)
       navigation.show();
});
```

**EDIT :** Added the condition to show the ul only when there are slides

Comment: Unfortunately what that does is hide the ul element on load and then appears even when there is no list items to be shown.

Comment: There you go, @ChristopherBurton

Comment: Thank you, Billy. Worked out great.